# Discrimination in Yakov's blessings to his sons

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, blessing, parashat-vayeishev, vayechi

1. Yaakov had learned "the hard way" what his discrimination of his sons leads to.
2. The Gemmorah ([Shabbos 10b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.10a?lang=bi)) rules that:

> "... אמר רב **לעולם אל ישנה אדם בנו בין הבנים** שבשביל משקל שני סלעים מילת שנתן יעקב ליוסף יותר משאר בניו נתקנאו בו אחיו ונתגלגל הדבר וירדו אבותינו למצרים":
>
> ... Rav said: **A person should never distinguish one of his sons from among the other sons by giving him preferential treatment.** As, due to the weight of two sela of fine wool [meilat] that Jacob gave to Joseph, beyond what he gave the rest of his sons, in making him the striped coat, his brothers became jealous of him and the matter unfolded and our forefathers descended to Egypt.

Nevertheless, Yakov [*does not learn the lesson and*] when blessing his sons uses vastly different languages:

- Yehuda gets a very lengthy prise and blessing.
- Reuben, Levi, and Shimon got scolded.
- Others get statements/blessings of different length and "depth" - some relate to the whole tribe and some only hint to one renown descendant.

Although we don't see additional fights between the brothers after those blessings, I still wonder, **why the blessing differ so much**?

Comment: There those who learn that these are not conevential blessings ,rather Yaakov is explaining what each tribe represents, and what needs to be done ,or avoided.

Comment: @sam Please continue... Wasn't Yehuda the one to "sin" the most?

Comment: The "blessings" were also a prohphsey ,so Yaakov said what he saw as appropriate to teach tribe .

Comment: @sam I understand your point, but you miss mine - discrimination. One child gets prised and one scolded - is that Yosef and bros v2.0?

Comment: What is he supposed yo do ,when it's given over as a prophesy

Comment: @sam Maybe shut up or rearrange thing so the differences wouldn't be so sound?

Comment: The simple answer is he ended with bracha for all ,like Rashi (49:28) says : וזאת אשר דבר להם אביהם ויברך אותם: והלא יש מהם שלא ברכם אלא קינטרן. אלא כך פירושו וזאת אשר דבר להם אביהם מה שנאמר בענין. יכול שלא ברך לראובן שמעון ולוי, תלמוד לומר ויברך אותם, כולם במשמע:

Comment: As far as the rebuke ,Rashi says in Devarim 1:3 ויהי בארבעים שנה בעשתי עשר חדש באחד לחדש: מלמד שלא הוכיחן אלא סמוך למיתה. ממי למד, מיעקב שלא הוכיח את בניו אלא סמוך למיתה. אמר, ראובן בני, אני אומר לך מפני מה לא הוכחתיך כל השנים הללו, כדי שלא תניחני ותלך ותדבק בעשו אחי.

Comment: @sam I'm sorry I don't really see when you start talking about the discrimination. Rashi says "well, some were really harsh, but no matter, they were all blessings anyway". Does this answer the discrimination? I don't see how. Would you be surprised if Levy and Shimon would kill Yehudah for his blessings? I wouldn't.

Comment: See my comment about giving rebuke before one dies,he was giving rebuke to those that dis somthing wrong ,nothing to do with favoring other shevatim